# An integral related to Gamma value.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, closed-form, elliptic-integrals

We have:
$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin{x}\log{(\tan{(x/2))}+x}}{\sqrt{\sin{x}}(\sin{x}+1)}dx=\pi-\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}\Gamma{(1/4)}^{2}}{16}-\frac{\sqrt{2}\pi^{5/2}}{2\Gamma{(1/4)}^{2}}\tag{1}.$$
As other integrals, Mathametica and Wolfram Alpha are unable to deal with it
(see [Wolfram Alpha response](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+%28sin%28x%29log%28tan%28x%2F2%29%29%2Bx%29%2F%28sqrt%28sinx%29%28sinx%2B1%29%29+dx+from+x%3D0+to+pi%2F2&lang=es)).
The proof I have is not elementary and it is based on the following identity:
$$\Im\left(K(\sqrt{\frac{2k}{1+k}})\right)=\Im \left(K(\sqrt{\frac{1-k}{1+k}})-K(\sqrt{\frac{1+k}{1-k}})\cdot\sqrt{\frac{1+k}{1-k}}\right),\tag{2}$$
where: $$K(k)=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^{2}{x}}},\tag{3}$$
is the complete elliptic integral of the first kind. The proof follows from $(2)$ integrating both sides carefully.

**Question:**
Can we prove $(1)$ using only Feynman's trick and Beta function? Thanks for your cooperation.

Comment: Have you tried letting $t=\tan(x/2)$ ?

Comment: Yes, but this change doesn't seems to work @Zima

Comment: Assuming that the $1\sqrt {..} $ is over the complete denominator, by  numerics NIntegrate and N the results are different.

Comment: @RolandF Don't think so: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=NIntegrate%5B%28Sin%5Bx%5D+Log%5BTan%5Bx%2F2%5D%5D+%2B+x%29%2F%28Sqrt%5BSin%5Bx%5D%5D+%28Sin%5Bx%5D+%2B+1%29%29%2C+%7Bx%2C+0%2C+pi%2F2%7D%5D&lang=es and https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=pi-Sqrt%282pi%29Gamma%281%2F4%29%5E2%2F16-sqrt%282%29pi%5E%285%2F2%29%2F%282Gamma%281%2F4%29%5E2%29&lang=es

Comment: NIntegrate[(Sin[x] Log[Tan[x/2]] + x)/Sqrt[
 Sin[x] + Sin[x]^2], {x, 0, \[Pi]/2}]  =  0.257026    //  \[Pi] - Sqrt[2 \[Pi] ] Gamma[1/4]^2/16  - 
 Sqrt[2] (\[Pi]^(5/2))/(2 Gamma[1/4]^2)=
0.141216

Comment: @RolandF the denominator of your integral doesn' match the OP's one, so the results are different.

Comment: The different representations in the links to alpha are different.  I tried the first link. With only sin^(-1/2) the two expressions are identical up to 128 decimals.

Comment: @RolandF As I said I have a proof of $(1)$

Comment: Better to display the formula clearly, eg cancel the srqt@sine in the denominator. Proof by personal confirmation or word of honour  is common but not accepted in all countries. As far as I read comments, you are using integration by differentiation with respect to a parameter.

Comment: @RolandF as soon as possible I will post my solution since we have a proof from Po1nomyal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

---

Let $\mathcal{I}$ denote the value of the definite integral in question:

$$\mathcal{I}:=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{d}\theta\,\frac{\theta+\sin{\left(\theta\right)}\ln{\left(\tan{\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)}\right)}}{\left[1+\sin{\left(\theta\right)}\right]\sqrt{\sin{\left(\theta\right)}}}\approx0.141216.$$

---

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}
&=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{d}\theta\,\frac{\theta+\sin{\left(\theta\right)}\ln{\left(\tan{\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)}\right)}}{\left[1+\sin{\left(\theta\right)}\right]\sqrt{\sin{\left(\theta\right)}}}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{2}{1+t^{2}}\cdot\frac{2\arctan{\left(t\right)}+\left(\frac{2t}{1+t^{2}}\right)\ln{\left(t\right)}}{\left(1+\frac{2t}{1+t^{2}}\right)\sqrt{\frac{2t}{1+t^{2}}}};~~~\small{\left[\theta=2\arctan{\left(t\right)}\right]}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{2\left[2\arctan{\left(t\right)}+\left(\frac{2t}{1+t^{2}}\right)\ln{\left(t\right)}\right]}{\left(1+t\right)^{2}\sqrt{\frac{2t}{1+t^{2}}}}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{2\arctan{\left(\frac{1-u}{1+u}\right)}+\left(\frac{1-u^{2}}{1+u^{2}}\right)\ln{\left(\frac{1-u}{1+u}\right)}}{\sqrt{\frac{1-u^{2}}{1+u^{2}}}};~~~\small{\left[t=\frac{1-u}{1+u}\right]}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{2\left[\arctan{\left(1\right)}-\arctan{\left(u\right)}\right]-2\left(\frac{1-u^{2}}{1+u^{2}}\right)\operatorname{artanh}{\left(u\right)}}{\sqrt{\frac{1-u^{2}}{1+u^{2}}}}\\
&=2\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{\arctan{\left(1\right)}}{\sqrt{\frac{1-u^{2}}{1+u^{2}}}}-2\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{\arctan{\left(u\right)}}{\sqrt{\frac{1-u^{2}}{1+u^{2}}}}-2\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\,\sqrt{\frac{1-u^{2}}{1+u^{2}}}\operatorname{artanh}{\left(u\right)}\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{1+u^{2}}{\sqrt{1-u^{4}}}-2\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\,\sqrt{\frac{1+u^{2}}{1-u^{2}}}\arctan{\left(u\right)}\\
&~~~~~-2\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\,\sqrt{\frac{1-u^{2}}{1+u^{2}}}\operatorname{artanh}{\left(u\right)}\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1+\sqrt{x}}{4x^{3/4}\sqrt{1-x}};~~~\small{\left[u=\sqrt[4]{x}\right]}\\
&~~~~~-2\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\,\left[\sqrt{\frac{1+u^{2}}{1-u^{2}}}\arctan{\left(u\right)}+\sqrt{\frac{1-u^{2}}{1+u^{2}}}\operatorname{artanh}{\left(u\right)}\right]\\
&=\frac{\pi}{8}\left[\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1}{x^{3/4}\sqrt{1-x}}+\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{x}\sqrt{1-x}}\right]\\
&~~~~~-2\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\,\left[\sqrt{\frac{1+u^{2}}{1-u^{2}}}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{u}{1+x^{2}u^{2}}+\sqrt{\frac{1-u^{2}}{1+u^{2}}}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{u}{1-x^{2}u^{2}}\right]\\
&=\frac{\pi}{8}\left[\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,x^{-3/4}\left(1-x\right)^{-1/2}+\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,x^{-1/4}\left(1-x\right)^{-1/2}\right]\\
&~~~~~-\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,(2u)\left[\frac{1}{1+x^{2}u^{2}}\sqrt{\frac{1+u^{2}}{1-u^{2}}}+\frac{1}{1-x^{2}u^{2}}\sqrt{\frac{1-u^{2}}{1+u^{2}}}\right]\\
&=\frac{\pi}{8}\left[\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac14,\frac12\right)}+\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac34,\frac12\right)}\right]\\
&~~~~~-\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\,(2u)\left[\frac{1}{1+x^{2}u^{2}}\sqrt{\frac{1+u^{2}}{1-u^{2}}}+\frac{1}{1-x^{2}u^{2}}\sqrt{\frac{1-u^{2}}{1+u^{2}}}\right]\\
&=\frac{\pi}{8}\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac14,\frac12\right)}+\frac{\pi}{8}\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac34,\frac12\right)}\\
&~~~~~-\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}v\,\left[\frac{1}{1+x^{2}v}\sqrt{\frac{1+v}{1-v}}+\frac{1}{1-x^{2}v}\sqrt{\frac{1-v}{1+v}}\right];~~~\small{\left[u^{2}=v\right]}\\
&=\frac{\pi}{8}\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac14,\frac12\right)}+\frac{\pi}{8}\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac34,\frac12\right)}-\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\int_{1}^{0}\mathrm{d}w\,\frac{(-2)}{\left(1+w\right)^{2}}\\
&~~~~~\times\left[\frac{1}{1+x^{2}\left(\frac{1-w}{1+w}\right)}\sqrt{\frac{1}{w}}+\frac{1}{1-x^{2}\left(\frac{1-w}{1+w}\right)}\sqrt{w}\right];~~~\small{\left[v=\frac{1-w}{1+w}\right]}\\
&=\frac{\pi}{8}\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac14,\frac12\right)}+\frac{\pi}{8}\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac34,\frac12\right)}-\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}w\,\frac{2}{\left(1+w\right)\sqrt{w}}\\
&~~~~~\times\left[\frac{1}{\left(1+w\right)+x^{2}\left(1-w\right)}+\frac{w}{\left(1+w\right)-x^{2}\left(1-w\right)}\right],\\
\end{align}$$

and then,

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}
&=\frac{\pi}{8}\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac14,\frac12\right)}+\frac{\pi}{8}\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac34,\frac12\right)}-\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}w\,\frac{2}{\left(1+w\right)\sqrt{w}}\\
&~~~~~\times\left[\frac{1}{\left(1+x^{2}\right)+\left(1-x^{2}\right)w}+\frac{w}{\left(1-x^{2}\right)+\left(1+x^{2}\right)w}\right]\\
&=\frac{\pi}{8}\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac14,\frac12\right)}+\frac{\pi}{8}\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac34,\frac12\right)}\\
&~~~~~-\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}w\,\frac{1}{\left(1+x^{2}\right)}\left[\frac{1}{1+\left(\frac{1-x^{2}}{1+x^{2}}\right)w}+\frac{w}{\left(\frac{1-x^{2}}{1+x^{2}}\right)+w}\right]\frac{2}{\left(1+w\right)\sqrt{w}}\\
&=\frac{\pi}{8}\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac14,\frac12\right)}+\frac{\pi}{8}\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac34,\frac12\right)}\\
&~~~~~-\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}w\,\frac{1}{x^{2}}\left[\frac{2}{1+w}-\frac{\left(\frac{1-x^{2}}{1+x^{2}}\right)}{1+\left(\frac{1-x^{2}}{1+x^{2}}\right)w}-\frac{\left(\frac{1-x^{2}}{1+x^{2}}\right)}{\left(\frac{1-x^{2}}{1+x^{2}}\right)+w}\right]\frac{1}{\sqrt{w}}\\
&=\frac{\pi}{8}\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac14,\frac12\right)}+\frac{\pi}{8}\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac34,\frac12\right)}\\
&~~~~~-\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{2}{x^{2}}\left[\frac{2}{1+y^{2}}-\frac{\left(\frac{1-x^{2}}{1+x^{2}}\right)}{1+\left(\frac{1-x^{2}}{1+x^{2}}\right)y^{2}}-\frac{\left(\frac{1-x^{2}}{1+x^{2}}\right)}{\left(\frac{1-x^{2}}{1+x^{2}}\right)+y^{2}}\right];~~~\small{\left[\sqrt{w}=y\right]}\\
&=\frac{\pi}{8}\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac14,\frac12\right)}+\frac{\pi}{8}\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac34,\frac12\right)}\\
&~~~~~-\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2}{x^{2}}\left[\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{2}{1+y^{2}}-\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\left(\frac{1-x^{2}}{1+x^{2}}\right)}{1+\left(\frac{1-x^{2}}{1+x^{2}}\right)y^{2}}-\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\left(\frac{1-x^{2}}{1+x^{2}}\right)}{\left(\frac{1-x^{2}}{1+x^{2}}\right)+y^{2}}\right]\\
&=\frac{\pi}{8}\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac14,\frac12\right)}+\frac{\pi}{8}\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac34,\frac12\right)}\\
&~~~~~-\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2}{x^{2}}\left[\frac{\pi}{2}-\sqrt{\frac{1-x^{2}}{1+x^{2}}}\arctan{\left(\sqrt{\frac{1-x^{2}}{1+x^{2}}}\right)}-\sqrt{\frac{1-x^{2}}{1+x^{2}}}\arctan{\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1-x^{2}}{1+x^{2}}}}\right)}\right]\\
&=\frac{\pi}{8}\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac14,\frac12\right)}+\frac{\pi}{8}\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac34,\frac12\right)}-\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2}{x^{2}}\left[\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{2}\sqrt{\frac{1-x^{2}}{1+x^{2}}}\right]\\
&=\frac{\pi}{8}\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac14,\frac12\right)}+\frac{\pi}{8}\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac34,\frac12\right)}-\pi\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1}{x^{2}}\left[1-\sqrt{\frac{1-x^{2}}{1+x^{2}}}\right].\\
\end{align}$$

Evaluating the remaining integral by parts, we find

$$\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1}{x^{2}}\left[1-\sqrt{\frac{1-x^{2}}{1+x^{2}}}\right]
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\left[1-\sqrt{\frac{1-x^{2}}{1+x^{2}}}\right]\frac{d}{dx}\left[-\frac{1}{x}\right]\\
&=\left[-\frac{1-\sqrt{\frac{1-x^{2}}{1+x^{2}}}}{x}\right]_{x=0}^{x=1}-\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\left[-\frac{1}{x}\right]\frac{d}{dx}\left[1-\sqrt{\frac{1-x^{2}}{1+x^{2}}}\right];~~~\small{I.B.P.}\\
&=-1+\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1}{x}\cdot\frac{2x}{\left(1+x^{2}\right)^{2}\sqrt{\frac{1-x^{2}}{1+x^{2}}}}\\
&=-1+\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2}{\left(1+x^{2}\right)\sqrt{1-x^{4}}}\\
&=-1+\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1-2x^{2}-x^{4}}{\left(1+x^{2}\right)\sqrt{1-x^{4}}}+\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1+x^{2}}{\sqrt{1-x^{4}}}\\
&=-1+\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{d}{dx}\left[x\sqrt{\frac{1-x^{2}}{1+x^{2}}}\right]+\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1+x^{2}}{\sqrt{1-x^{4}}}\\
&=-1+\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1+x^{2}}{\sqrt{1-x^{4}}}\\
&=-1+\frac14\left[\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac14,\frac12\right)}+\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac34,\frac12\right)}\right].\\
\end{align}$$

Hence,

$$\mathcal{I}=\pi-\frac{\pi}{8}\left[\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac14,\frac12\right)}+\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac34,\frac12\right)}\right].\blacksquare$$

---

Comment: Wow, what an effort! +1 for sure.

Comment: Well this uses only Beta function (+1) and accepted. Best all.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution with a bit contour integration, which is, if you ask me, elemantery.

Firstly, substitute $x=\dfrac\pi2-2\arctan t$ to get
$$
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin{x}\log{(\tan{(x/2))}+x}}{\sqrt{\sin{x}}(\sin{x}+1)}dx\\
=\underbrace{2\int_0^1 \left(\sqrt{\frac{1+t^2}{1-t^2}} \cot ^{-1}(t)-\sqrt{\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}} \tanh ^{-1}(t)\right) dt}_{J}-\frac\pi2\underbrace{\int_0^1 \sqrt{\frac{1+t^2}{1-t^2}}dt}_{K}
$$
$K$ can be simply done via Beta function
$$
K=\int_0^1 (1-t^4)^{-1/2}dt+\int_0^1 t^2(1-t^4)^{-1/2}dt=\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^2}{4 \sqrt{2 \pi }}+\frac{\pi ^{3/2} \sqrt{2}}{\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^2}
$$
One should notice that this contributes to the last two terms.

To show that $J=\pi$ would be the tricky part. Consider the function
$$
f(z)=\frac12\log \left(\frac{z+1}{z-1}\right) \exp \left(\frac{1}{2} \log \left(\frac{z^2-1}{z^2+1}\right)\right)
$$
and integrate on the contour illustrated below

[image]

The branch cuts are marked red, and $f(z)$ is chosen to be real when $z>1$ is real.

$f(z)$ has only four poles, namely $i^k\quad k=0,1,2,3$. Verify that
$$
\lim_{z\to i^k}f(z)=0
$$
Thus, small perturbations can be made to bypass them without changing the integral and only the eight segments matter. Arguments should be treated carefully since multiple poles are involved. All eight integrals are long and similar, so only two is shown here.
$$
\int_1 f(z)dz=\int_1^0\frac12\left(\log \left(\frac{1+t}{1-t}\right)-\pi i\right) \exp \left(\frac{1}{2} \log \left(\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}\right)+\frac{\pi i}2\right)dt\\
=-i\int_0^1 \sqrt{\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}} \tanh ^{-1}(t) dt-\frac\pi2\int_0^1 \sqrt{\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}}dt
$$

$$
\int_2 f(z)dz=\int_0^1\frac12\left(2i\tan^{-1}(t)-\pi i\right) \exp \left(\frac{1}{2} \log \left(\frac{1+t^2}{1-t^2}\right)-\frac{\pi i}2\right)idt\\
=i\int_0^1 \sqrt{\frac{1+t^2}{1-t^2}} \cot ^{-1}(t) dt
$$

... (rest six)

After some simplification one arrives that
$$
\oint f(z)dz=4i\int_0^1 \left(\sqrt{\frac{1+t^2}{1-t^2}} \cot ^{-1}(t)-\sqrt{\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}} \tanh ^{-1}(t)\right) dt=2iJ
$$
Note that $z=\infty$ is a simple pole of $f(z)$, so we can apply the [residue at infinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_at_infinity)
$$
\underset{z=\infty}{\text{Res }}f(z)=-\underset{w=0}{\text{Res }}\frac{f(1/w)}{w^2}=-1
$$
Hence,
$$
\oint f(z)=-2\pi i \underset{z=\infty}{\text{ Res }}f(z)=2\pi i\\
J=\pi
$$
and we are done.

Comment: Hi  (+1)  for the solution, but I wanted to use only Beta Function and Feynman's trick. The solution is of course elementary. I will wait to other responses before accept it. Best all.

Comment: Can we complete it with the six remaining? Thanks in advance.

Comment: They are really not so important. One can find all from the following rule: mark the integral on the segments counter-clockwisely as $1,2,\cdots,8$. Note that $(1,8),(2,3),(4,5),(6,7)$ are pairs on different sides of a branch line, so respectively their difference is only a sign on the real part. Moreover, $(1,5),(2,6),(3,7),(4,8)$ are seperated by two poles, which means that they are actually the same respectively. Now all values can be deduced from $1,2$ shown above.